# Scala: How to wait for a Future

Tags: scala, future

In the following code snippet, method `bookExists` invokes method `find` to determine whether the book identified by the specified id exists:

```
class BookStore {

  def find(id: String): Future[Option[Book]] = {
    // read from db
    ...
  }

  def bookExists(id: String): Boolean = {
    find(id).map {
      case Some(_) => true
      case _ => false
    }.recover {
      case e => false
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the class above doesn't compile probably because I need to wait until the `Future` actually completes. I always get the following error message:

```
[error] /home/j3d/test/BookStore.scala:118: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Boolean]
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]         ).map {
[error]               ^
```

What's the correct way to handle this case?

Comment: Why not `.map(_.nonEmpty)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are awaiting the result you are mapping this Future[Option[Book]] to another future  of type Future[Boolean]. Without the await the computation will take place after the find Future completes (if at all).  Change your return type:

```
  def bookExists(id: String): Future[Boolean] = {   
    find(id).map { _ match {  // '_' in the map is a Option[Book] extracted from the Future[Option[Book]] find returns
        case Some(_) => true  // '_' in the match is Book extracted from the Option[Book] in the match statement
        case _ => false
      }.recover {
        case e => false
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally you'd return `Future[Boolean]` and thus defer the requirement to have the answer for as long as possible.

But if it is important to block until the answer is available, then use `scala.concurrent.Await` (preferably wrapped in a `Try` to catch errors).