# Map value from a Future to Object and not Future[Object]

Tags: scala, future

I have a function that return a `Future[State]` and another function that I need return a `StateSimplified` object

```
//class State
case class State(id: String, label: String, postalCode: String, extension: Long...)

//class StateSimplified
case class StateSimplified(id: String, label: String)
```

Now I have this function

```
def getSimple(relationId: Int): Future[StateSimplified] = {
  repository.findStateByRelationId(relationId).map(state => 
    StateSimplified(id = state.id, label = state.label))
}
```

The `repository.findStateByRelationId(relationId: Int)` is a function that find a state from a related table, that function returns a `Future[State]`
The problem is that the I need a `StateSimplified` not a `Future[StateSimplified]` because the StateSimplified I need to put it in an other class

```
case class City(id: Int, name: String, population: Long,..., state: StateSimplified)
```

How can I map the result from `repository.findStateByRelationId(relationId: Int)` to a `StateSimplified` and not a `Future[StateSimplified]`

**Edit:**
In this [suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312491/scala-how-to-wait-for-a-future) the title is **How to wait for a Future** but the answer mark as solution suggest that the function return a Future, and don't want to return Future in my function because later that object is going into another different one `City` have an attribute called `state` that is of type `StateSimplified`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala: How to wait for a Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312491/scala-how-to-wait-for-a-future)

Comment: When you have a `Future` you only have two options, you either keep returning a `Future` until the end of the world, or you wait for it. Awaiting blocks a thread, which is not ideal for performance, thus most apps do the first thing and most modern web frameworks are capable of returning `Future` _(or other similar types like `IO`)_ as the response for a request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Await a future, receive an either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417317/await-a-future-receive-an-either)

Comment: Take a look at this question, it might inerest you [scalas-for-comprehension-with-futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045936/scalas-for-comprehension-with-futures). It helps you learn how to manage futures without too many .flatMaps and their execution order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, when you get a `Future`, you have 2 options:

1. continue to work with it, using `map`, `flatMap` or other operations. All of this is **non-blocking**.
2. wait for it to return a value. This is **blocking**.

Most of the time you want to do (1) up until the main class of your application . In any decent web framework, you don't even need (2), the framework will handle that for you.

Back to your case, this means that you should do something like this:

```scala
val futureCity: Future[City] = getSimple(...).map { stateSimplified =>
  // Build or set in a City
  City(...)
}

// Then work with the Future[City] rather than the City directly using map or flatMap...
```